# How to resolve StackOverflowError while mapping properties in Kotlin data class?

Tags: java, kotlin, stack-overflow

I am trying to do mapping between the properties of multiple data classes (as shown below) but getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB`:

```
2021-12-04 00:37:22.801 com.abcE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sxm.nissan.connect.mx, PID: 15025
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3109)
        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:275)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:249)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:241)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
        at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:59)
        at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68)
        at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68)

2021-12-04 00:37:22.802 com.abcI/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1562(103KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 68MB/74MB, paused 538us total 511.886ms
2021-12-04 00:37:22.804 com.abcE/AndroidRuntime:     at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68)
        at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68)
2021-12-04 00:37:23.178 com.abcI/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 678273(35MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(1344KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 53MB/59MB, paused 486us total 339.741ms
2021-12-04 00:37:23.937 com.abcI/chatty: uid=10142(u0_a142) com.abcidentical 5303 lines
2021-12-04 00:37:23.937 com.abcE/AndroidRuntime:     at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68)
        at  com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68)
2021-12-04 00:37:23.937 com.abcE/AndroidRuntime:     at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getMainSubscriber(UserDetailResponse.kt:86)
        at com.abc.presenter.onUserDetailSuccess(AccountDetailPresenter.java:282)
        at com.abc.model.UserDetailServiceImpl.handleResponse(UserDetailServiceImpl.kt:50)
        at com.abc.model.UserDetailServiceImpl.handleResponse(UserDetailServiceImpl.kt:20)
        at com.sxm.connect.shared.model.util.SXMTelematicsService$1.success(SXMTelematicsService.java:62)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Here are the files:

**UserDetailResponse.kt**

```
data class UserInfoResponse(
        val id: String,
        val accountType: String,
        val alternatePhone: String,
        val alternatePhoneType: String,
        val billingCity: String,
        val billingCountry: String,
        val billingId: String,
        val billingPostalAddress1: String,
        val billingPostalAddress2: String,
        val billingPostalCode: String,
        val billingStateProvince: String,
        val currency: String,
        val effectiveRoles: List<EffectiveRole>,
        val givenName: String,
        val mailingCity: String,
        val mailingCountry: String,
        val mailingPostalAddress1: String,
        val mailingPostalAddress2: String,
        val mailingPostalCode: String,
        val mailingStateProvince: String,
        val primaryPhone: String,
        val primaryPhoneType: String,
        val secondaryPhone: String,
        val secondaryPhoneType: String,
        val suffix: String,
        val surname: String,
        val userName: String,
        val vehicles: List<Vehicle>,
) {
        val contactPoints: ContactPoints
                get() = run {
                        var address = Address()
                        val addressList = arrayListOf<Address>()
                        address.id = id
                        address.street = billingPostalAddress1
                        address.addressLine1 = billingPostalAddress1
                        address.city = billingCity
                        address.state = billingStateProvince
                        address.postalCode = billingPostalCode
                        address.country = billingCountry
                        addressList.add(address)
                        address = Address()
                        address.id = id
                        address.street = mailingPostalAddress1
                        address.city = mailingCity
                        address.state = mailingStateProvince
                        address.postalCode = mailingPostalCode
                        address.country = mailingCountry
                        addressList.add(address)
                        contactPoints.addresses = addressList

                        var phone = Phone()
                        val phoneList = arrayListOf<Phone>()
                        phone.value = primaryPhone
                        phoneList.add(phone)
                        phone = Phone()
                        phone.value = primaryPhone
                        phoneList.add(phone)
                        contactPoints.phones = phoneList
                        contactPoints
                }

        val mainSubscriber: MainSubscriber
                get() = run {
                        mainSubscriber.firstName = givenName
                        mainSubscriber.lastName = surname
                        mainSubscriber.contactPoints = contactPoints
                        mainSubscriber
                }
}
```

**ContactPoints.java**

```
public class ContactPoints implements Parcelable {
  private List<Phone> phones = null;
  private List<Email> emails = null;
  private List<Address> addresses = null;

  public List<Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
  }

  public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
  }

  public List<Email> getEmails() {
    return emails;
  }

  public void setEmails(List<Email> emails) {
    this.emails = emails;
  }

  public List<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
  }

  public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
  }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address implements Parcelable {

  private String id;

  private String street;

  private String name;

  private String state;

  private String addressLine2;

  private String country;

  private String city;

  private String region;

  private String addressLine1;

  public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
  }

  public void setSubRegion(String subRegion) {
    this.subRegion = subRegion;
  }

  public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
  }

  public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
  }

  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }


  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }


  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }


  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }



  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }



  public String getState() {
    return state;
  }


  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }


  public String getAddressLine2() {
    return addressLine2;
  }



  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }



  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public String getRegion() {
    return region;
  }

  public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
  }

  public String getAddressLine1() {
    return addressLine1;
  }

  public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
  }

  public Address() {
  }
```

These are the lines corresponding to the errors:

> ```
>     at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:59) : address.id = id
> ```

> ```
>     at com.abc.UserDetailResponse.getContactPoints(UserDetailResponse.kt:68) : var phone = Phone()
> ```

Comment: The `contactPoints` getter calls itself by referencing `contactPoints` so it is infinitely calling itself recursively.

Comment: @Tenfour04 are you referencing to `mainSubscriber.contactPoints = contactPoints`?

Comment: No I’m talking about the code inside your getter for `contactPoints`. Look at its last three lines.